# Can display image on webpage just cant get its name

Tags: javascript, html, file

I can display an image:

```
...
<img src="img.png">
...
```

So I know its on the server, but I cant simply print its name.

For example, if its in the root directory, I don't know how to do something like:

```
var directory = "./"
for file in get_files(directory):
    console.log(file) # should print the files in the directory
```

Thanks for any help.

Comment: I don't get why its being downvoted, i've looked everywhere.

Comment: What is `get_files`? Please provide a [mcve]. Why do you use Python syntax in JavaScript?

Comment: Are you asking about _server-side_ JavaScript here? Because client-side JavaScript can not read any directories on the server. (It could at most try and parse the directory listing that gets returned when the directory itself gets requested via URL, _if_ the server is configured to respond with one, and not a 403 Forbidden.)

Comment: That is just pseudocode, I can't figure out the proper code to get a list of all the files in the directory.

Comment: Does the server API support file listing?

Comment: If I can click on an image and read it, download it, etc... whats the security problem in reading its name programmatically?

Comment: @jabaa Do you mean like directory listing / indexing? I've tried adding a `.htaccess` file, but it didn't fix it.

Comment: @tok1n — Getting the URL of an image in the document you are viewing is **very different** from reading the images in a directory on the server (which is what the pseudo-code you wrote is clearly trying to do).

Comment: You could write an endpoint like `/api/get_files?url=/`. Since you're talking about `.htaccess`, I assume you have Apache httpd. It's common to write backend logic for Apache httpd with PHP or CGI.

Comment: @Quentin I thought its just, a file is being served, you as a client, can read it, download it, etc... but it isn't that simple.

Comment: For example, https://tok1n.codeberg.page/fs_test/uploads/pdf/sun.png that is a file on the server, that I can read the name of and download, what is the code where i can read and download it programmatically?

Comment: @tok1n — A moment ago you were talking about finding out what the URL was, now you're asking about reading and downloading it. You need to make it clear what you are actually trying to acheive here!

Comment: With JavaScript: `fetch('https://tok1n.codeberg.page/fs_test/uploads/pdf/sun.png')`

Comment: @Quentin I'm trying to read the name of it so I can essentially download it, or at least, I want to refer to it maybe as a blob or something.

Comment: @tok1n — What does the name have to do with downloading it? You download things from URLs not file names. In the example you just gave  (`https://tok1n.codeberg.page/fs_test/uploads/pdf/sun.png`) you already have the URL.

Comment: You have to know the name of the file before you can download it. If you don't know the name, you have to ask the server. If the server doesn't tell you the name, you're out of luck.

Comment: Well so for example, ifI know  `https://tok1n.codeberg.page/fs_test/uploads/pdf/` and I `https://tok1n.codeberg.page/fs_test/uploads/pdf/sun.png` is obviously available, how do I ask the server "hey, can you tell me whats in `uploads/pdf`?" and it will say "sun.png".

Comment: Does the server provide a file listing or an API for this? If not, you can't do anything. (You could guess filenames, of course)

Comment: In the general case, *you can't*, that isn't a feature of HTTP. See my answer.

Comment: @jabaa I think github has an `api.github` that you can issue GET requests but haven't found anything yet in the docs for codeberg.

Comment: _"how do I ask the server "hey, can you tell me whats in uploads/pdf?" and it will say sun.png."_ - _only_ be requesting `https://tok1n.codeberg.page/fs_test/uploads/pdf/`, and then processing the formatted directory listing you get returned - _if_ you get one in the first place. If the server is not _configured_ to list the directory contents, when the directory itself gets requested - then you simply _can't_ get the information you want. (Unless the server is explicitly providing some sort of API for this purpose.)

Comment: Have you checked https://codeberg.org/api/swagger? I don't know codeberg and I haven't checked the docs.

Comment: @CBroe Okay thanks. Is it when it shows a file tree at that path that it is available to query like that?

Comment: It depends. The file tree could be dynamically generated with JavaScript. That could make it very complex.

Comment: I think `GET /repos/{owner}/{repo}/contents/{filepath}` is what you're looking for: https://codeberg.org/api/swagger#/repository/repoGetContentsList and https://codeberg.org/api/swagger#/repository/repoGetContents

Comment: Okay, i've got a bit to go off now, thanks @jabaa.

Comment: @jabaa One last thing, i can't find anything on what the prefix of the GET request is, is it meant to be something like `https://codeberg.org/api/swagger/repos/tok1n/fs_test/contents/uploads/pdf`?

Comment: nvm, i figured it out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JavaScript running in the browser has no way of determining what URLs are recognised by an HTTP server without either:

- Being told about them (e.g. by `<img src>`)
- Making an HTTP request and seeing what the response is

The is **no** standard HTTP feature for getting listing of URLs that are available under a given path.

**Sometimes** a web server will be configured so that if you ask for `/foo/` then it will return an HTML document with links to every resource directly under `/foo/`.

If that is the case you could use [the `fetch` api](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch) to make a request for that HTML document and then [parse it](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMParser), [query for the links](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll), then loop over the result and [read the `href` attributes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getAttribute).

In that isn't the case, as in the example you gave in the comments where `https://tok1n.codeberg.page/fs_test/uploads/pdf/` is a 404 Not Found error page that that approach won't work unless you are capable of changing the server to provide a directory listing.

Comment: Is the directory listing where you navigate to it and it shows an unstylized file tree? Also, if it can be changed would it be changed via a `.htaccess` file? Thanks

Comment: Often. Depends on the HTTP server.